# How to make angular identify module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an nrwl nx angular project right now I have two libraries one material home and one ui elements. Inside Ui elements I have datatable component which I want to use in my material home. I used the selector and imported the module of UI Elements to material module. In Ui Elements module I have my datatable component inside the export and declaration part. But Angular gives me still this error:

```
Error: libs/material/src/lib/material-home/material-home.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'moniesta-data-table' is not a known element:
1. If 'moniesta-data-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'moniesta-data-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

This is how my html looks:

```
<moniesta-data-table></moniesta-data-table>
```

Material Module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, MatButtonModule, UiElementsModule],
  declarations: [
    MaterialHomeComponent,
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

And finally the UiElementsModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MatButtonModule, MatTableModule],
  declarations: [
    DataTableComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DataTableComponent
  ]
})
export class UiElementsModule {}
```

In my general understanding it should work like this, because I have imported UIElementsModule into MaterialModule. So what could be the error?

Comment: just add schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] into your UiElementsModule

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I had to work and can only look at weekends to this project. I did what you said but the error was not fixed